# Bokeh - Grouped axis with RangeTool

Tags: list, indexing, bokeh

Is it possible to create a figure with a grouped axis AND a `RangeTool`?

This example demonstrates the RangeTool https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/range_tool.html.

I have a list of tuples `factors` which I want to use as a grouped axis:
`[('2017','Jan'),('2017','Feb')..('2019','Oct')]`

In the example, the initial pan on the plot seems to be set by `x_range` in

```
p = figure(plot_height=300, plot_width=800, tools="xpan", toolbar_location=None,
           x_axis_type="datetime", x_axis_location="above",
           background_fill_color="#efefef", x_range=(dates[1500], dates[2500]))
```

However, to use a grouped x axis, one must use `FactorRange` ala `x_range=FactorRange(*factors)`. I've tried various forms of indexing of `factors` with `FactorRange` and cannot get it to work. Is such a thing possible in Bokeh?

The plot in here demonstrates an example of a grouped axis:
https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/bar_mixed.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RangeTool` assumes an underlying numeric axis, so there is not a direct way to accomplish this. The only route I could see would be to simulate a categorical axis by using a numerical axis with a fixed ticker and tick labels that correspond to the "categories" you want, and then to plot the bars using the corresponding numerical coordinates.